# Usage of gerund instead of simple tense with "after": "after I have breakfast" vs. "after having breakfast"

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, gerunds

Are the following two answers totally equal in meaning?

*What are you doing? I'm doing my English homework. Do you do your homework in the morning?*

> 1. Yes, I do English after I have breakfast.
> 2. Yes, I do English after having breakfast.

Comment: I think you want "Do you do youR homework".

Comment: Yes, they are both equal.  However, not all verbs work this way -- some use the infinitive, while others use the gerund.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case they are both equal. Don't be too quick to generalise from it, though.